# read file txt in langage c

Tags: c, file, fopen

it's a cesar encrypt in process
the problem is when i open a file with the method "openFile"

/* it's been 2 years since I've touched the c language, I'm getting back to it */

i have this code other file :

```
//method to encrypt a char
char encrypt(char c, int jump) {
    int overflow = 0;
    char res = c;
    char tabChars[26] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',
                   'i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q',
                   'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof (tabChars);i++) {
        if(c == tabChars[i]) {
            if(i+jump > 25) {
                overflow = i+jump - 26;
                res = tabChars[overflow];
            } else if(i+jump <= 25) {
                res = tabChars[i+jump];
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
    };

void writeInFile(FILE* file) {
    //todo
};

// error here
void openFile(char* file) {
    FILE* f = fopen(file, "r");
    printf("\nopen file : %s\n", file);
    char c;
    while((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(f);
};
```

and main code :

```
int jump = 5;
char c = 't';
printf("\nletter change with : --%c--\n",encrypt(c,jump));

char* file = "taget/to/message.txt";
openFile(file); // error here
```

but i have a error :

```
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
```

why doesn't work ? thanks all

Comment: Error from where? The compiler? When you run the program? How does this relate to `qt` that you have tagged? Please provide complete code as a [mre] and a clearer log of exactly where the error is coming from.

Comment: Unrelated to your current problem, but please note that [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an **`int`**. Which is rather important when you want to compare `c` to the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: Perhaps related to your problem: ***Always*** check for errors. What happens if `fopen` fails and returns a `NULL` pointer?

Comment: common error `char c;` => `int c;`

Comment: Names are significant... The function does not simply open the nominated file (if it can), but reads its content and writes that to `stdout`... The function name is deceptive...

Comment: stackoverflow doesn't wan't post all code, wait sorry

Comment: i have change c to int but the problem is here to

Comment: i have add if(f) and error is  not here anymore

Comment: Unrelated: `tabChars` is basically useless because for any `i` in `[0..25]` `tabChars[i]` is the same as `'a' + i`. At least on 99.99% of all platforms.

Comment: thx, It's been 2 years since I've touched the c language, I'm getting back to it

Comment: `if(i+jump > 25)` You might revisit C operators. Take a look at modulo operator: `%`.That whole `if` can be replaced by `res = tabChars[(i+jump) % 26];`

Comment: effectively, i didn't think of that, thx

Answer (score 0):

with if(f) // works, thx all for your comments

```
void openFile(char* file) {
FILE* f = fopen(file, "r");
if(f) {
    printf("\nopen file : %s\n", file);
    char c;
    while((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    fclose(f);
} else {
    printf("\nopen error...\n");
}
};
```

out of function :

[image]

Comment: `getc` returns an `int`, and EOF is an integer value, so you really need `int c;` here. Also note how `putchar` actually takes `int` parameter.

Comment: try the code, works, i have my text of my txt file, but thx

Comment: It probably does not work for any compiler where `char` is unsigned (it can be signed or unsigned). And it will not work for binary data, because binary data may contain the same value as `EOF` converted to `char`. You need to use `int` because `EOF` must be a value outside of all possilbe `char` values.